# Leader of heading and subheading with css

Tags: css

I need to achieve following thing with css.

```
. Heading
|
|
|----Subheading
|--------|
|--------|
|--------|
|--------|----subHeading of subheading
|--------|--------------|
|--------|--------------|
|--------|--------------|
|--------|--------------|
|--------|--------------|--------SubHeading of subheading
```

Any one know name of this structure ?? or CSS to achieve this ?

Comment: Looks like a nested set of lists to me,

Comment: what's wrong with the question?? Y'all are down voting it?

Comment: @Paulie_D There are many input fields are placed under the heading.
I need to show heading and subheading in this format. so that user can check where exactly they are in nested subheadings

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="heading">
 header
</div>
<div class="subheading">
 subheader
</div>
<div class="subsubheading">
 subsubheading
</div>
<div class="subsubsubheading">
 subsubsubheading
</div>
<style>
.heading{
 text-align: left;
 float:left;

}
.subheading{
 text-align:left;
 float:left;
 margin-top:100px;
}
.subsubheading{
 text-align:left;
 float:left;
 margin-top:200px;
}
.subsubsubheading{
 text-align:left;
 float:left;
 margin-top:300px;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Yes, you just need to use floats and `margin-top` like so.

**CSS**

```
.heading{
    text-align: left;
    float:left;

}
.subheading{
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    margin-top:100px;
}
.subsubheading{
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    margin-top:200px;
}
.subsubsubheading{
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    margin-top:300px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="heading">
    header
</div>
<div class="subheading">
    subheader
</div>
<div class="subsubheading">
    subsubheading
</div>
<div class="subsubsubheading">
    subsubsubheading
</div>
```

Comment: Y'all are down voting it, but it works. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I need that exact structure with that "|"  and "." , your ans is not appropriate according to the question.
But i am not the one who down voting you ans.